# MVC JSONP TreeStore

Tags: sencha-touch, jsonp

I'm starting coding with Sencha Touch and I would like to do the same thing as below, but at distance:

```
MyApp.search = new Ext.data.TreeStore({
   model: 'ListItemSearch',
   proxy: {
   type: 'ajax',
       url: 'search.json',
       reader: {
           type: 'tree',
           root: 'items'
       }
   }
});
```

It's working fine, but I'd like to make it at distance with JSONP like this:

```
MyApp.search = new Ext.data.TreeStore({
   model: 'ListItemSearch',
   proxy: {
   type: 'ajax',
       url: 'http://www.test.com/search.json',
       reader: {
           type: 'tree',
           root: 'items'
       }
   }
});
```

I don't know how to code this, and the examples that I tried didn't work.

How can I do this?

Comment: MyApp.search = new Ext.data.TreeStore({
   model: 'ListItemSearch',
   proxy: {
   type: 'scripttag',
       url: 'http://www.test.com/search.php',
       reader: {
           type: 'tree',
           root: 'items'
       }
   }
});

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

if your JavaScript code isn't running at the same domain as your ajax request (test.com) then you will have security issues.  Check to make sure the proxy type 'ajax' is using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)
I think you have to use the sencha [JSONP](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/?class=Ext.util.JSONP) library to do this.